# How to get image from dynamic url using urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib3

I have generated a url from product code like,

```
code: 2555-525
url : www.example.com/2555-525.png
```

But when fetching a url, it might be a different name format on server,like

```
www.example.com/2555-525.png
www.example.com/2555-525_TEXT.png
www.example.com/2555-525_TEXT_TEXT.png
```

Sample code,

```
urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()
```

could we pass the url like `www.example.com/2555-525*.png` ?

Comment: [Here's a great page](https://pyformat.info/) on Python's string formatting.

Comment: Well, I don't have anything to add. This is a really basic and trivial thing in Python and if you don't know how to do it, you might want to go through some tutorials first.

Comment: @Sevanteri i have tried a lots of method but i cant succeed!

Comment: This world is doomed... `"www.example.com/{code}_{text}".format(code="2555-525", text="TEXT")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using wildcards in URLs is useless in most cases because

- the interpretation of the part of the URL after `http://www.example.com/` is totally up to the server - so `http://www.example.com/2555-525*.png` might have a meaning to the server but but propably has not
- normally (exceptions like WebDAV exist) there is no way of listing ressources in a collection or existing URLs in general apart from trying them one-by-one (which is unpractical) or scraping a known site for URLs (which might be incomplete)

For finding and downloading URLs automatically you can use a [Web Crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) or Spider.

Comment: Thanks for neat and clean explanation! +1

Comment: There propably are python-libraries for crawling/spidering sites but I do not know any specific one.